# Google visualisation query fail

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I wonder why one of my queries is failing from time to time (not always) it apparently happens on **Edge navigators** (not chrome), is there a way to automatically query again if it fails? Is this normal?
It happens on the load of the file that populates the markers (16'000) on the Google map.

The website is https://florida.evictionprotection.org/ 
Thanks for helping me understand.

```js
  function handleQueryResponse4(response) {
    data4 = JSON.parse(response.getDataTable().toJSON())
    dataProp.table4 = { headers: [...data4.cols], rows: [...data4.rows] }
    for (let i = 0; i < data4.cols.length; i++) {
      dataProp.table4.headers[i] = dataProp.table4.headers[i].label
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < data4.rows.length; i++) {
      let tempRow = [];
      for (let j = 0; j < data4.rows[i].c.length; j++) {
        // creation of rows to add later one by one
        tempRow[j] = cleanRowsContent(dataProp.table4.rows[i].c[j])
      }
      //adding the rows to the array i will be using
      dataProp.table4.rows[i] = tempRow
    }
    loadingData.innerHTML = `
      <p>OR</p>
      <div><button style="display: block" id = "find-me" onclick="findMyLocation()">Find my location</button></div><br/>
      <p>Look for covered properties in your area. Click a marker to see the protected property’s address and the associated program through which it is protected.</p>`
    setMarkers(map)
  }

  function getDataSheets() {
    var query4 = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xEz5wfWSwXbAgWhgvJxfxSDhNGf5w8hqVpAFbbAViEo/gviz/tq?tqx=out:json&sheet=Sheet4')
    query4.send(handleQueryResponse4)
  }
```

[image]

Comment: will you please share the code, rather than a picture of the code?

Comment: @WhiteHat I edited the post, does this help? Thank you.

Comment: thanks, I thought it would help, but now I'm confused. why do you need to use the raw json from the data table, when you can just use the data table itself? -- `response.getDataTable()` -- for instance, to loop the columns and rows, you can use --> `response.getDataTable().getNumberOfColumns()` -- & -- `response.getDataTable().getNumberOfRows()` -- to get a value --> `response.getDataTable().getValue(rowIndex, colIndex)` -- there are many [methods](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#methods) you can use. when parsing the raw json appears to throw the error...